# vim-go autocompletion not working

Tags: vim, autocomplete, go

I recently installed [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) using pathogen, but the autocompletion feature is not working. If I am using  it only shows commands I've already used.
My .vimrc has

```
filetype plugin on

" Enable autocompletion
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
" Select keyword as you type
:set completeopt=longest,menuone
```

Do I need more than just this plugin? The other feature I have tested so far are working (:GoRun, syntax highlighting).
This is on a Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `syntaxcomplete#Complete` ships with Vim, not the Go filetype plugin, and it has very limited capabilities (basically, just offering the language's keywords). No wonder you're disappointed.

The `ftplugin/go.vim` file sets the correct, custom completion of the vim-go plugin:

```
setlocal omnifunc=go#complete#Complete
```

So, just ensure that the `'filetype'` setting is correct (`go`), and that you don't have any additional configuration that overrides the plugin's.

```
:verbose setlocal omnifunc?
```

can tell you.

Comment: `:verbose setlocal omnifunc?` outputs `omnifunc=go#complete#Complete Last set from ~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle/vim-go/ftplugin/go.vim`, which matches what you suggested.  But, it isn't working for me.  C-x,C-o works.  `neocomplete` seems to be working for other languages, like bash scripts: it shows entire paths instantly just typing `#!/bin/`.  Disabling `neocomplete` disabled that type of function, so i know that plugin working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you've accepted the answer, even though a solution has not been posted. If you managed to fix it, could you share how ? Since I'm facing the same problem as you. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Are you typing C-X C-O to open the autocompletation window? This works fine for me.

On the other hand, if you want to get real-time completion (completion by type) install the following plugins `YCM` or `neocomplete`

Comment: This was an eye-opener for me. Had no idea this was a built-in thing. I expected real-time pop-up windows.

Comment: actually reading a little further down the docs (https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/doc/vim-go.txt), it turns out you can with neocomplete (vim) or deoplete (vim8 / neovim only)

Answer (score 0):

If none of these suggestions solves your problem, try killing gocode from a terminal:

```
gocode exit (or killall gocode it that fails)
gocode -s -debug
```

In case of startup failure due to a lingering unix socket, simply remove it and try again. Once everything is working, you can terminate the debug enabled gocode process (the plugin will autostart as needed)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. default gocode pkg seems to be no longer maitained. so update it with the one below.
my go and vim versions:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2
go version go1.16.4
```

---

follow the steps below:

```
gocode exit 
go get -u github.com/mdempsky/gocode
```

---

run gocode in debug mode

```
gocode -s -debug
```

try the autocomplete.(vim-go C+X C+O)

viola! you should see the list like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who were using Coc but getting some of autocomplete:

open coc configs using `:CocConfig`
and paste the following:

```
    "languageserver": {
        "golang": {
            "command": "gopls",
            "rootPatterns": ["go.mod", ".vim/", ".git/", ".hg/"],
            "filetypes": ["go"]
        }
    }
```